# What does CString::GetBuffer() with no size parameter do?

Tags: c++, mfc

Perhaps I'm going insane, but I have tried every search combination I can think of, and I can't find a definition for `CString::GetBuffer()` with no parameters.  Every reference I look up describes `CString::GetBuffer( int )`, where the `int` parameter passed in is the max buffer length.  The definition in the header is for `CSimpleStringT::GetBuffer()`.  That gave me the following link, which at least acknowledges the existence of the parameterless version, but offers no description of its behavior.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sddk80xf.aspx#csimplestringt__getbuffer

I'm looking at existing C++ (Visual Studio) code that I don't want to change if I don't have to, but I need to know the expected behavior of `CString::GetBuffer()`.  I'd appreciate it if someone could explain it or point me to some documentation on it.

Comment: It doesn't say [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sddk80xf.aspx#csimplestringt__getbuffer) but it looks to be implied that you just get the buffer.

Comment: Sorry, link is there now.

Comment: It's not explicit, but it seems to me like it's equivalent to `GetBuffer(0)`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that would be great answer if you can find some corroborating evidence for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [tl;dr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR)

Call [`CString::GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring).

---

This is asking the wrong question for the wrong reasons. Just to get it out of the way, here is the answer from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffer):

> **Return Value**
>   An `PXSTR` pointer to the object's (null-terminated) character buffer.

This is true for both overloads, with and without an explicit length argument. When calling the overload taking a length argument, the internal buffer may get resized to accommodate for increased storage requirements, prior to returning a pointer to that buffer.

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282990/what-does-cstringgetbuffer-with-no-size-parameter-do#comment91514933_52283203), it becomes apparent, that the question is asking for the wrong thing altogether. To learn why, you need to understand what the purpose of the `GetBuffer()` family of class members is: To *temporarily* disable enforcement of `CString`'s class invariants<sup>1</sup> for *modification*, until establishing them again by calling one of the [ReleaseBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#releasebuffer) members. The primary use case for this is to interface with C code (like the Windows API).

The important information is:

- `GetBuffer()` should only be called, if you plan to directly modify the contents of the stored character sequence.
- Every call to `GetBuffer()` must be matched with a call to `ReleaseBuffer()`, before using any other `CString` class member<sup>2</sup>. Note in particular, that `operator PCXSTR()` and the destructor are class members.
- As long as you follow that protocol, the controlled character sequence will always be null-terminated.

Given your actual use case (`Log.Print("%s\n", myCstring.GetBuffer())`), none of the previous really applies. Since you do not plan to actually modify the string contents, you should access the immutable `CString` interface (e.g. [GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) or [operator PCXSTR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#operator_pcxstr)) instead. This requires const-correct function signatures (`TCHAR const*` vs. `TCHAR*`). Failing that, use a `const_cast` if you can ensure, that the callee will not mutate the buffer.

There are several benefits to this:

- It is semantically correct. If all you want is a view into the character string, you do not need a pointer to a mutable buffer.
- There are no superfluous copies of the contents. `CString` implements copy-on-write semantics. Requesting a mutable buffer necessitates copying the contents for shared instances, even if you are going to throw that copy away immediately after evaluating the current expression.
- The immutable interface cannot fail. No exceptions are thrown when calling `operator PXCSTR()` or `GetString()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The relevant invariants are: `1` The controlled sequence of characters is always null-terminated. `2` `GetLength()` returns the count of characters in the controlled sequence, excluding the null terminator.*

<sup>2</sup> *It is only strictly required to call one of the `ReleaseBuffer()` implementations, if the contents were changed. This is often not immediately obvious from looking at the source code, so* always *calling `ReleaseBuffer()` is the safe option.*

Answer (score 6):

Although the msdn documentation doesn't really say what `GetBuffer` without a parameter does, the MFC source code reveals the answer:

`return( m_pszData );`

So it just returns a pointer to the underlying character buffer.  (It also checks to see if the internal data is shared and forks/copies it first).

The code is in atlsimpstr.h

Complete function:

```
PXSTR GetBuffer()
{
    CStringData* pData = GetData();
    if( pData->IsShared() )
    {
        Fork( pData->nDataLength );
    }

    return( m_pszData );
}
```

Comment: The documentation for GetBuffer( int ) indicates the string in the buffer will not be NULL terminated.  If that's the case, the way it's being used in our code is only working by luck.   Log.Print("%s\n", myCstring.GetBuffer());

Comment: Luck is definitely not the way to code @GreggH!  Please accept if you like the answer :)

Comment: my point exactly!  However, I went back and read the description again and the non terminated string remark was related to editing the content and doesn't apply in this case.  Thanks you all for your input!

Comment: @gre: You are using the wrong tool altogether. Given your `Log.Print()` example, you should be calling [CString::GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring), to receive a pointer to an **immutable** character sequence. Calling `GetBuffer` instead of `GetString` is an extremely common anti-pattern, usually caused by failure to provide const-correct function signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is inconclusive. Looking at ATL sources available here (https://github.com/dblock/msiext/blob/d8898d0c84965622868b1763958b68e19fd49ba8/externals/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/atl71/atlsimpstr.h - I do not claim to know if they are official or not) it looks like `GetBuffer()` without arguments returns the current buffer, cloning it before if it is shared.

On the other hand, `GetBuffer(int)` with size is going to check (through the call to `PrepareWrite` and possibly `PrepareWrite2`) if the current buffer size is greater than requested, and if it is not, it will allocate the new buffer - thus matching MSDN description.

On a side note, `PrepareWrite` seems to become quite creative in how it checks for two conditions:

```
PXSTR PrepareWrite( __in int nLength )
{
    CStringData* pOldData = GetData();
    int nShared = 1-pOldData->nRefs;  // nShared < 0 means true, >= 0 means false
    int nTooShort = pOldData->nAllocLength-nLength;  // nTooShort < 0 means true, >= 0 means false
    if( (nShared|nTooShort) < 0 )  // If either sign bit is set (i.e. either is less than zero), we need to copy data
    {
        PrepareWrite2( nLength );
    }

    return( m_pszData );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows API functions often require the input of a character buffer of a certain length. Then use the `GetBuffer(int)` version. The following code snippet illustrates this and the difference between `GetBuffer()` and `GetString()` and the importance of calling `ReleaseBuffer()` after calling `GetBuffer()`:

```
CStringW FullName;
if(::GetModuleFileNameW(nullptr,FullName.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), MAX_PATH) <= 0)
     return 0;                                //GetBuffer() returns PXSTR
FullName.ReleaseBuffer();                     //Don't forget!
FullName = L"Path and Name: " + FullName;
std::wcout << FullName.GetString() << L"\n";  //GetString() returns PCXSTR
```